# Save loaded images from a web browser with Webkit in Python

Tags: python, webkit

today I started developing my Python app. Using GTK and Webkit for Python. And now I have a problem: I want to save a loaded image from the web browser to my computer but I can't download it as a normal image because it's a dynamic image generated by PHP.
With VB.NET I managed to do it, but I want my application to be cross-platform.

Any idea how can I do it?

I want to "clone" the image shown in the web browser, but I can't download it because it is dynamic. In vb.net you execute the command copy and then you save it.

EDIT 2: I have found the solution:

```
web.copy_clipboard()
clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
image = clipboard.wait_for_image()
image.save("test.png", "png")
```

First make sure that you selected the image.

Comment: Clarify what it is you are trying to do. How are you trying to save the image? What code are you using to try and save it?

Comment: For example, in the web browser there is an image element, this image is dynamic, for example, a captcha. I want to save this image to my computer. I'm using this code: (http://pastebin.com/ybzAXrEv)

Comment: What happens when you use this code? Do you get an error? What do you expect to happen? Edit your original post to include these items (Including the code you are using for the attempt) to help someone help you with the issue.